# Google Apps Script API: Internal error encountered when creating deployments via POST request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a deployment for a Google Apps Script project using the Google Apps Script API. I am issuing a POST request to [https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{scriptId}/deployments](https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7BscriptId%7D/deployments) as per the official documentation. However, I am receiving a 500 Internal error as follows:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I have verified that my scriptId is accurate, and I have configured the necessary permissions in my Google Cloud Project. The Apps Script API has also been enabled.

Interestingly, I encountered the same issue when testing this API endpoint directly on the developers.google.com test API interface.

Is there a step I might be overlooking that could trigger this error? Has anyone faced a similar issue and found a solution? Any assistance or insights would be highly valued.

Comment: Can you provide your current script for requesting the API?

Comment: @Tanaike I got the same error using API endpoint directly on the developers.google.com test API interface